# tar extracts with invalid permissions - is it an intended behavior?

Tags: permissions, tar, umask

Recently a `tar.gz` archive broke my script. Steps to reproduce:

```
# this is a Python package distributed through PyPi
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/b3/e8/0a829f58ff6068f94edf74877f2e093aae945482c96ade683ef3cafdfcad/EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5.tar.gz
# tar exit status is 0 (i.e. not a broken archive)
tar -zxvf EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5.tar.gz
ls -l EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5
```

Result:

```
ls: cannot access 'EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5/scripts': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5/setup.py': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5/LICENSE.txt': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5/PKG-INFO': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5/EasyExtend': Permission denied
ls: cannot access 'EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5/README.txt': Permission denied
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? EasyExtend
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? LICENSE.txt
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? PKG-INFO
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? README.txt
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? scripts
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? setup.py
```

Though everything was done under non-superuser account, umask was not applied to newly extracted files.

**Question**: is it a bug, feature or an invalid archive?

**Question**2: is there an elegant way to force default permissions on such files?

**UPD**: my umask is 0002. `sudo ls -l` gives the right permissions:

```
sudo ls -l EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5
total 28
drw-rw-r-- 7 username username 4096 Sep 19  2009 EasyExtend
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 1559 May 16  2006 LICENSE.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username  342 Sep 19  2009 PKG-INFO
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username  585 Aug 13  2008 README.txt
drw-rw-r-- 2 username username 4096 Sep 19  2009 scripts
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username username 5296 Aug 15  2008 setup.py
```

Comment: These are perfectly valid permissions, they just don't include letting you read them :).  In terms of tar, surely it's a feature?  But the archive sounds messed up.

Comment: Re umask, I would assume the explanation here is correct; umask is purely a subtractive thing (or a bitmask, if you're a programmer).  It doesn't make sense to say umask is not applied on the basis that there are _missing_ permission bits.  https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/tar-no-same-permissions-does-not-work-4175489723/

Comment: @sourcejedi thanks, that is the answer. The extracted directory is missing x bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are perfectly valid permissions, they just don't include letting you read them :). In terms of tar, surely it's a feature? But the archive sounds messed up.

Re umask, I would assume the explanation [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/tar-no-same-permissions-does-not-work-4175489723/) is correct; umask is purely a subtractive thing (or a bitmask, if you're a programmer). It doesn't make sense to say umask is not applied on the basis that there are missing permission bits.

To grant executable permission for all directories, you can conveniently use `chmod -R a+X EasyExtend-3.0.2-py2.5`